# Spivak: Are partial fractions decompositions that involve less terms than a full-fledged application of partial fractions guaranteed to exist?

Tags: calculus, integration

The two theorems that introduce partial fractions decomposition in Spivak's *Calculus* are

> **Theorem:** Every polynomial function
>
> $$q(x)=x^m+b_{m-1}x^{m-1}+...+b_0$$
>
> can be written as a product
>
> $$q(x)=(x-\alpha_1)^{r_1}\cdot ...\cdot
>  (x-\alpha_k)^{r_k}(x^2+\beta_1x+\gamma_1)^{s_1}\cdot ...\cdot
>  (x^2+\beta_lx+\gamma_l)^{s_l}$$
>
> where $r_1+...+r_k+2(s_1+...+s_l)=m$

Which says that every m-th order polynomial can be written as the product of powers of linear and quadratic functions.

Then

> **Theorem:** If $n<m$ and
>
> $$p(x)=x^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+...+a_0$$
>
> $$q(x)=x^m+b_{m-1}x^{m-1}+...+b_0$$
>
> $$=(x-\alpha_1)^{r_1}\cdot ...\cdot 
>  (x-\alpha_k)^{r_k}(x^2+\beta_1x+\gamma_1)^{s_1}\cdot ...\cdot 
>  (x^2+\beta_lx+\gamma_l)^{s_l}$$
>
> then $p(x)/q(x)$ can be written in the form
>
> $$\frac{p(x)}{q(x)}=\left [
>  \frac{a_{1,1}}{(x-\alpha_1)}+...+\frac{a_{1,r_1}}{(x-\alpha_1)^{r_1}}
>  \right ]+...+\left [
>  \frac{a_{k,1}}{(x-\alpha_k)}+...+\frac{a_{k,r_k}}{(x-\alpha_k)^{r_k}}
>  \right ]+$$
>
> $$\left [
>  \frac{b_{1,1}x+c_{1,1}}{(x^2+\beta_1x+\gamma_1}+...+\frac{b_{1,s_1}x+c_{1,s_1}}{(x^2+\beta_1x+\gamma_1)^{s_1}}
>  \right ]+...+\left [
>  \frac{b_{l,1}x+c_{l,1}}{(x^2+\beta_lx+\gamma_l}+...+\frac{b_{l,s_l}x+c_{l,s_l}}{(x^2+\beta_lx+\gamma_l)^{s_l}}
>  \right ]$$

Let's say we want to solve the integral

$$\int\frac{x^3+7x^2-5x+5}{(x-1)^2(x+1)^3}$$

It seems that a straight up use of partial fractions decomposition as shown in the second theorem above would be

$$\int\frac{x^3+7x^2-5x+5}{(x-1)^2(x+1)^3}=\int\left [ \frac{A}{x-1}+\frac{B}{(x-1)^2}+\frac{C}{x+1}+\frac{D}{(x+1)^2}+\frac{E}{(x+1)^3} \right ]\tag{1}$$

And try to find the five variables $A,B,C,D, E$.

However, we can also do just

$$\int\frac{x^3+7x^2-5x+5}{(x-1)^2(x+1)^3}=\int\left [ \frac{A}{(x-1)^2}+\frac{B}{(x+1)^3} \right ]\tag{2}$$

and find $A=1, B=4$.

Then

$$\int\frac{x^3+7x^2-5x+5}{(x-1)^2(x+1)^3}=\int\left [ \frac{1}{(x-1)^2}+\frac{4}{(x+1)^3} \right ]$$

$$=-(x-1)^{-1}-2(x+1)^{-2}$$

Decomposition $(1)$ is guaranteed to exist based on the second theorem above.

**Two questions**

- Is decomposition $(2)$ guaranteed to exist as well?
- How do we know to try decomposition $(2)$ to solve the integral in an easier way? It seems that it was luck that the numerators were just constants. They could have involved $x$ and then the integration wouldn't be as easy. Is identifying this just a question of trial and error, or was there some indication in the original integral that this decomposition would work?

Comment: Try this with numerator $1+x$ and denominator $x^2$. You do need the two terms, even though one may vanish sometimes.

Comment: 1) Yes, the theorem guarantees the existence of a decomposition i.e. existence of specified constants, 2) I didn't quite understand the question - are you asking if there is an easier way? Then the main thing is what to understand by simpler. This theorem guarantees the decomposition, so, integration.

Comment: @zkutch The theorem guarantees the existence of the decomposition in $(1)$. The question is if the decomposition in $(2)$ is guaranteed to exist. That is a decomposition with $A=C=D=0$ in $(1)$.

Comment: Firstly let me ask you - in the last term degree 3 is it a mistake or intentionally?

Comment: @zkutch I've corrected the initial integral. It has a degree 3 expression in the denominator.

Comment: I do not see how it can be guaranteed in the general case (2), this can happen for specific polynomials. For the general case, it may be possible under some additional conditions, but in the general case we have a guarantee only for (1).

Comment: @zkutch, which brings us to the second question: is attempting decomposition $(2)$ simply a question of trial and error (at which one gets better with practice), or was there something a priori that indicated that particular decomposition would exist and work?

Comment: I think answer is my previous comment.

Comment: The partial fraction decomposition in this manner is unique, so no you can't get around it. If what you're starting off with looks simple, then try to decompose by inspection (you need lots of practice and experience for this). Otherwise, do it the systematic way; if you get something simple with many coefficients 0, then thank your lucky stars, otherwise, that's just the way things work and you have to deal with it.

Comment: To supplement the existing good comments, we can approach the question "from the other end" to see why "Decomposition (2) does not always exist": Write down an arbitrary rational function of the form (1), i.e., with the highest-degree terms, but at least one non-zero lower-degree term. Now put this over a common denominator, obtaining $f(x)$. As peek-a-boo says, the partial fractions decomposition of $f(x)$ is the sum we started with, i.e., it contains summands other than the two of top degree.